# Loading data from database for BB10

Tags: qt, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I followed the database creation app on http://developer.blackberry.com/native/sampleapps/ but I can't figure out how can I create the database/retrieve data when my app loads. Can someone help me with good reference books for using sqlite3 with cascades, I can't find any good source for it.

Comment: Do you want a QT only solution or a QML one?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways, but I used this one so far (it's not perfect but good enough).

- First save [customsqldatasource.cpp](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/blob/master/quotes/src/customsqldatasource.cpp) and [customsqldatasource.h](https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/blob/master/quotes/src/customsqldatasource.h) inside your `/src` directory.
- Open your `applicationui.cpp` and add to the top

  ```
  #include "customsqldatasource.h"
  ```

and add this inside `ApplicationUI` to expose it to QML:

```
qmlRegisterType<CustomSqlDataSource>("com.myapp.data", 1, 0, "CustomSqlDataSource");
```

- Add `LIBS   += -lbbdata` to your .pro file
- add your database in `/assets`; location is up to you, just make sure it matches `source` in `CustomSqlDataSource`
- add `import com.myapp.data 1.0` to your `.qml` file

Within `attachedObjects` add this:

```
CustomSqlDataSource {
    id: asynkDataSource
    source: "sql/mydatabase.db"
    query: "SELECT * FROM recent_searches GROUP BY fromCity, toCity ORDER BY id DESC"

    onDataLoaded: {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            //use data
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is add the following line inside `onCreationCompleted` to load it

```
asynkDataSource.load();
```

I hope I didn't forget anything. A few important things: `/assets` folder is read only, therefore your .db is copied to `/data` folder (this script does it).